Incompatible pointer types error only on my local machine and not on online IDE
I was brushing up on my Design Patterns in C here, and while trying to run this object method design example they have on their site:
#include <stdio.h>

// Define a structure to represent an object
typedef struct {
    // Data members
    int value;

    // Function pointer for a method
    void (*print)(const struct MyObject *);
} MyObject;

// Method to print the value of the object
void printValue(const MyObject *obj) {
    printf("Object value: %d\n", obj->value);
}

// Function to initialize an object
void initializeObject(MyObject *obj, int initialValue) {
    obj->value = initialValue;
    obj->print = &printValue; // Assign the function pointer
}

int main() {
    // Create an instance of MyObject
    MyObject myObj;

    // Initialize the object
    initializeObject(&myObj, 42);

    // Use the object's method
    myObj.print(&myObj);

    return 0;
}


I get these errors:
main.c:9:30: warning: declaration of 'struct MyObject' will not be visible outside of this function [-Wvisibility]
  void (*print)(const struct MyObject *);
                             ^
main.c:20:14: error: incompatible function pointer types assigning to 'void (*)(const struct MyObject *)' from 'void (*)(const MyObject *)' [-Wincompatible-function-pointer-types]
  obj->print = &printValue; // Assign the function pointer
             ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~
main.c:31:15: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'MyObject *' to parameter of type 'const struct MyObject *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  myObj.print(&myObj);
              ^~~~~~
2 warnings and 1 error generated.

This makes sense to me since the MyObject struct doesn't have the necessary visibility. It works just fine when I change it to:
typedef struct MyObject {
  // Data members
  int value;

  // Function pointer for a method
  void (*print)(const struct MyObject *);
} MyObject;

I'm just wondering why it compiles on all the online IDE's
Edit:
It gets compiled in the example provided in the link:
geeksforgeeks
As well as these:
tutorialspoint
codechef
Those were the first 3 that I tried, but i do see some now throwing the same errors

why it compiles on all the online IDE's This is not true: https://godbolt.org/z/nevzWbohW

In C, you are referencing 2 different structs: an anonymous struct with a typedef alias of MyObject and a totally separate struct type with a tag of MyObject that you have never defined. This should not compile. Are you sure you are using a C and not a C++ online compiler? In C, the struct tag namespace is different than the global namespace.

Please revise question and supply at least one instance of a online IDE where this compiles.

It gets compiled in the example provided in the link:
geeksforgeeks
As well as these:
tutorialspoint
codechef
Those were the first 3 that I tried, but i do see some now throwing the same errors

You want to edit your question with additional data instead of replying with a comment.

In this typedef declaration
typedef struct {
    // Data members
    int value;

    // Function pointer for a method
    void (*print)(const struct MyObject *);
} MyObject;

there are introduced two different type specifiers: an unnamed structure type specifier with the alias name MyObject and an incomplete structure type specifier struct MyObject in this line within the unnamed structure declaration
    void (*print)(const struct MyObject *);
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Moreover the scope of this type specifier struct MyObject is the function prototype scope. That is this declaration is not visible outside the function parameter list.
These types are not compatible.
To avoid the errors just change the declaration the following way
typedef struct MyObject {
    // Data members
    int value;

    // Function pointer for a method
    void (*print)(const struct MyObject *);
} MyObject;

Pay attention to that this assignment statement
obj->print = &printValue; // Assign the function pointer

may be also rewritten like
obj->print = printValue; // Assign the function pointer

because function designators used in expressions are implicitly converted to pointers to them.
As for compilers then it is implementation defined whether compilers will output warnings as errors and that depends on compiler options.
